# Scripting the cisco banner with Net::Appliance::Session

Tags: regex, perl, network-programming, cisco

Has anyone ran into this issue?  When the script gets to the banner text the script just hangs.

I am using `Net::Appliance::Session`

Here is the error I get in debug.  The rest of the script inserts code perfectly.  I did test what I read about adding a # to the banner for each line.  Same result.

```
banner login +
[   4.092880] tr   nope, doesn't (yet) match (?-xism:[\/a-zA-Z0-9._\[\]-]+ ?(?:\(config[^)]*\))? ?[#>] ?$)
[   4.093124] du   SEEN:
banner login +
[   4.093304] tr   nope, doesn't (yet) match (?-xism:[\/a-zA-Z0-9._\[\]-]+ ?(?:\(config[^)]*\))? ?[#>] ?$)
[   4.305872] du   SEEN:
Enter TEXT message.  End with the character '+'
[   4.306121] tr   nope, doesn't (yet) match (?-xism:[\/a-zA-Z0-9._\[\]-]+ ?(?:\(config[^)]*\))? ?[#>] ?$)
We had an issue when accessing the device : 10.49.216.74
The reported error was : read timed-out at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/Net/CLI/Interact/Transport/Wrapper/Net_Telnet.pm line 35
```

Here is a snip of code.

```
            my $session_obj = Net::Appliance::Session->new(
                host => $ios_device_ip,
                transport => 'Telnet',
                personality => 'ios',
                timeout => 60,
        );

#interace
        $session_obj->set_global_log_at('debug');
        eval {
                 # try to login to the ios device, ignoring host check
                $session_obj->connect(
                username => $ios_username,
                password => $ios_password,
                #SHKC => 0
        );
        # get our running config
        $version_info = $session_obj->begin_privileged;
        $session_obj->cmd('conf t');
        $session_obj->cmd('line con 0');
        $session_obj->cmd('exec-character-bits 8');
        $session_obj->cmd('international');
        $session_obj->cmd('line vty 0 4');
        $session_obj->cmd('exec-character-bits 8');
        $session_obj->cmd('international');
        $session_obj->cmd('line vty 5 15');
        $session_obj->cmd('exec-character-bits 8');
        $session_obj->cmd('international');
        $session_obj->cmd('exit');
        $session_obj->cmd('no banner login');
        $session_obj->cmd('banner login +');
        $session_obj->cmd('*************************************************************************');
        $session_obj->cmd('*                          test                                         *');
        $session_obj->cmd('*                                                                       *');
        $session_obj->cmd('*************************************************************************');
        $session_obj->cmd('+');
        $session_obj->cmd('no banner MOTD');
        $session_obj->cmd('banner motd +');
        $session_obj->cmd('*************************************************************************');
        $session_obj->cmd('*                          test                                         *');
        $session_obj->cmd('*                                                                       *');
        $session_obj->cmd('*************************************************************************');
        $session_obj->cmd('+');
        $session_obj->cmd('exit');
        $session_obj->cmd('write memory');
        $session_obj->end_privileged;
        # close down our session
        $session_obj->close;
};
```

Comment: Just to verify that the asterisk isn't screwing things up, try changing it to something else that isn't also a key character in a regular expression, like an underscore, and see if it makes a difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took way too long to figure this out...  spaces are not your friend.

```
$session_obj->cmd("banner login + \rline1\rline2\rline3\r+");
```

Example with my orginal problem:

```
$session_obj->cmd('*************************************************************************\r*                          test                                         *\r*                                                                  *\r*************************************************************************');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the regexp that matches the prompt before sending a new command you'll see that it requires a specific string that closely matches user, privileged or config mode of a router.

When you send the `banner login +` command you get the `Enter TEXT message.  End with the character '+'` followed by blank line from a router (instead of `Router(config)#` that your script expects. After a while it just times out since there is no match for the regexp.

The easiest solution is to try to send the whole banner in one command. Try concatenating your banner with a `\r` in one string and sending it as a one command that looks like (note the double quotes):

```
$session_obj->cmd("banner login + line1 \r line2 \r line3\r +");
```